# Jacobian of a matrix equation $X^2-BX-C$?

Tags: matrices

I need to find the critical points of a matrix equation $X^2-BX-C$, all matrices are square, $X$ is the solution to be found and $B,C$ are constant matrices. I have seen that I should find first the derivative (Jacobian) of the equation and then find its zeros, but the problem is how to find the derivative of a matrix with respect to a matrix?. Or How is the way you propose to solve this?.

Comment: What is a function ? Critical point exists if a function exists.

Comment: f(X)=X^2-BX-C, that is the function, the critical points are the zeros of f'(X) but i don't know how it works with matrices.

Comment: $c(t) = (X+th)^2-B(X+th)-C$ so that $0=c'(0)=hX+Xh-Bh$. If we let $h=[e_i\ 0\ ... \ 0]^T$ then $X$ is a diagonal. And if $h=I$ then $X=B/2$. Hence $B$ is a diagonal.

Comment: Solutions of  X^2−BX−C=0 could be critical points of f(X)=X^2−BX−C?. And about your answer B is not diagonal. So X depend on the structure of H? and why you call it as a vector? are you vectorizing matrices?

Comment: How should I determine different h and say what are solutions X for each one? How many cases of H should I propose?

Comment: I suggest making every notion clear to you before asking the question. Say critical point, Jacobian, matrix derivative. And then modify your problem and make it understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gina,  since you don't know how to derive a matrix function, I don't understand why you want to consider the critical points of such a function. Moreover you don't know what is a critical point !

(1) $f(X)=X^2-BX-C=0$ denotes the generic Riccati matrix equation. As Lee wrote 
$Df_X:H\rightarrow XH+HX-BH$ and $Df_X=X\otimes I+I\otimes X^T-B\otimes I$ (a Kronecker product, a $n^2\times n^2$ matrix, cf. wikipedia). $X$ is a critical point of $f$ iff $Df_X$ is not surjective, that is iff (2) $\det(X\otimes I+I\otimes X^T-B\otimes I)=0$. Thus the so called "singular solutions" are the common roots of (1) and (2). Of course, you cannot formally solve such a system. Choose a numeric instance. The singular solutions of (1) are the multiple solutions but also the solutions that are eventually in an algebraic subset of solutions of $>0$ dimension.

EDIT 1: Gina, I wrote: the MULTIPLE solutions...Consider the case when $B=0,n=2$.If $X=\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\z&t\end{pmatrix}$, then $Df_X=\begin{pmatrix}x&0&y&0\\0&x&0&y\\z&0&t&0\\0&z&0&t\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}x&z&0&0\\y&t&0&0\\0&0&x&z\\0&0&y&t\end{pmatrix}$. The critical points are solutions of $\det(Df_X)=4(x+t)²(tx-zy)=0$, that is $trace(X)=0$ or $\det(X)=0$. Case 1: $C=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&4\end{pmatrix}$. There are two double solutions (then $4$ solutions) $X=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&\pm 2\end{pmatrix}$ and these solutions are critical points. Case 2: $C=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&4\end{pmatrix}$. There are $4$ simple solutions $X=\begin{pmatrix}\pm 1&0\\0&\pm 2\end{pmatrix}$ that are NOT critical points.

EDIT 2. I removed the part concerning the points at infinity because they are not necessarily critical points in general case ! I give another instance (when $n=2$) that admits an algebraic set $S$ of solutions of dimension $1$. $X^2+diag(1,2)X=0$. You can easily verify that the elements of the part of $S$ that has dimension $1$ are all critical.

Comment: So do you mean solutions of $f(X)=X²−BX−C$ are singular points as well? How is it?. I have doubt about that because I have solved considering that $f'(X)=0$ is a critical point iff $I⊗(X-B)=-(X^t ⊗ I)$ and I have found that B must be diagonal but it is not. Do you know what I mean? So I conclude that there is not any critical point, because of the nature of B.